# Accepting a friend request, directly into a specific audience group

Tags: facebook, facebook-friend-request

Is there an option to accept a friend request for a person, directly into a specific audience group?

For instance, can I accept a friend directly into the Acquaintance group on Facebook, to automatically limit their viewing of my information, without having to manually add them immediately after accepting their request?

Is there a way to do this when ***I*** request someone?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. Even with the API, requests are split into

- Accept friend
- Place into list

So you will have to look for an application that accomplishes this as a batch operation; there are no applications that do this however, since the API call to accept friends are whitelisted to Facebook only.

So in summary, there is no way natively or otherwise to do this.